# Inserted Images are Blurry (not original resolution) in Visio 2016

Tags: resolution, image-editing, microsoft-visio-2016

In Microsoft Visio (2016) whenever I insert an image of higher quality it turns up super blurry. I have tried to disable the compression already but whenever I attempt to change the setting, not only does it not change the image, it re ticks the box! This has been causing more than a few headaches for me as I need *visible* images for an assignment that needs to be completed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it seems to work in Visio 2016.

1. Create your drawing and insert images; they will appear blurry
2. Save your drawing and close it
3. Locate the .vsdx-file in your file exporer
4. Unzip the file or edit it through e.g. 7-Zip. See [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp1MOemMh9k) on how to edit modern Office files
5. Locate the images under \visio\media. Find out which one you need to replace by opening each of them [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyzvP.png)
6. Replace the low quality imported image in the zip-file by the high quality image. Make sure you keep the same file name [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTq9b.png) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd2BH.png)
7. Close the zip file/restore it to a .vsdx-file
8. Reopen the file in Visio. You should now see the high quality version

Here is an example of the difference before and after the fix. I replaced the upper image: [Low quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfPzC.jpg) - [High quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbbKU.jpg)

Comment: Why do you unzip something that has zipped?

Answer (score 0):

Rescale the image with an app designed for maximum quality. Determine the dimension in pixels (length and height) and import the image into [Paint.Net](https://getpaint.net), an Open Source image manipulation app, or something with similar high quality scaling (which Microsoft Paint is *not*). Then, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> or **Image | Resize** and scale it down to the target size, select it again, and paste it into Visio, for a sharper result.

If you wish to rescale multiple images and save them before importing, Paint.Net also gives you the opportunity to save into PNG or JPG format and with the latter allows you to determine the degree of compression used when saving. Leave it at 100% for no compression of the JPG file.

Answer (score 0):

The zip workaround doesn't work in my case unfortunately.

The best I could do is:

1. save the image as .bmp file with 150 pixels/inch (saving properties)
2. import the picture to visio

This gives me the best resolution.
BMP files are not compressed when imported. All other image files are compressed automatically.

I hope that helps.

Kind regards
Riccardo